# HTML5 prevent refresh on submit but allow login save

Tags: jquery, html

I have a single page web site with a login. How do I get the browser to prompt to save login details but not refresh the page? I've tried capturing the form submit, which prevents the page refresh, but it also prevents the prompt to save password.

```
function signOn() {
    $(frmSignOn).submit(
        function (e) {
            var username = $("#iEmail").val();
            var password = $("#iPassword").val();
            //Do login stuff
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: What's `frmSignOn`? Okay, yeah, it does. As the form is not really submitted right, so it won't prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bellow code to prevent refresh but ask for login save:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var frmSignOn=$('form');
    $(frmSignOn).bind('submit', $(frmSignOn), function(event) {
        var form = this;

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        if (form.submitted) {
            return;
        }

        form.submitted = true;

        var username = $("#iEmail").val();
        var password = $("#iPassword").val();
        //Do login stuff

    });
});
```